# Lazy initialization of dependencies injected into constructor

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection, dependencies

I have a class where I am injecting two service dependencies. I am using Unity container.

```
public interface IOrganizer
{
    void Method1();
    void Method2();
    void Method3();
}

public class Organizer : IOrganizer
{    
    private IService1 _service1;
    private IService2 _service2;

    public Organizer(Iservice1 service1, IService2 service2)
    {
        _service1 = service1;
        _service2 = service2;
    }

    public void Method1()
    {
        /*makes use of _service1 and _service2 both to serve the purpose*/
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        /*makes use of only _service1 to serve the purpose*/
    }

    public void Method3()
    {
        /*makes use of only _service2 to serve the purpose*/
    }
}
```

While it all works, but somehow it smells because when I am only invoking `Method2` and `Method3`, unity unnecessarily creates an instance of another not required service. The code snippet here is just a sample for explanation purposes. In a real situation object graph of these injected services itself is quite deep.

Is there a better way to design and address this kind of scenario?

Comment: The class takes the dependencies because it _could_ use them, if you have seperated your concerns properly you shouldn't worry about whether or not an instance of a class will use a specific dependency _every time_, just the possibility that it _will_ use it

Comment: If `service1` and `service2` can be registered as *singleton*, they will only be created one time so there will be no cost with using the service that is not required for a specific method. That said, the overhead of instantiating an object in .NET is extremely low - we are literally getting into micro-optimizing territory here.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Whether constructing the object is fast or slow depends readically on what that object is.  Constructing an object that does nothing in the constructor is indeed very fast.  But some objects have lots of work to do in order to be constructed.

Comment: @Servy - Good point. But if following good DI practices [Injection Constructors should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/), so in the normal case that should not be a concern.

Comment: I read a  nice article a while back which I found interesting. Maybe it would be of some interest to you https://rehansaeed.com/asp-net-core-lazy-command-pattern/

Comment: Have you had a chance to take a look at the article? While it targeted .net-core I believe the concept is applicable in your scenario. Do you agree?

Comment: As I remember, unity supports lazy resolve, so you should be able to just inject Lazy<IService1> to your constructor and use that.

Comment: @Nkosi : Thanks !! Article looks to be interesting to address kind of scenario i posted.

Comment: @Evk I will look into it.

Comment: Voting to reopen this, as I believe I can answer this question in a fairly objective way.

Comment: @MarkSeemann : that would be great Mark because i see in day to day work this is one area where people always have some confusion.

Comment: @Nkosi : would you consider reopening the question.

Comment: @MarkSeemann : post is reopened and eager to hear your opinion :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think your sense of smell is competent. Most people would happily code like this without a second thought. I do agree, though, that there's a few code smells in a design like outlined in the OP.

I'd like to point out that I use the term *code smell* as in [Refactoring](http://amzn.to/YPdQDf). It's an indication that something *may* not be right, and it might be worthwhile to investigate further. Sometimes, such investigation reveals that there are good reasons that the code is as it is, and you move on.

There's at least two separate smells in the OP. They're unrelated, so I'll treat each one separately.

## Cohesion

A fundamental, but often forgotten concept of object-oriented design is that of *cohesion*. Think of it as a counter-force to *separation of concerns*. As Kent Beck once put it (the exact source escapes me, so I paraphrase), things that vary together, belong together, while things that vary independently should be separated.

Without the 'force' of cohesion, the 'force' of separation of concerns would pull code apart until you have extraordinarily small classes, and even simple business logic is spread across multiple files.

One way to look for cohesion, or lack thereof, is to 'count' how many class fields are being used by each method of a class. While only a crude indicator, it does trigger our sense of smell in the OP code.

`Method1` uses both class fields, so is no cause for concern. Both `Method2` and `Method3`, on the other hand, use only half of the class fields, so we could view that as indication of poor cohesion - a code smell, if you will.

How can you address that? Again, I wish to emphasise that a smell isn't guaranteed to be bad. It's only a reason to investigate.

Still, if you want to address the issue, I can't think of any other way than breaking up the class into several smaller classes.

The `Organizer` class in the OP implements the `IOrganizer` interface, so technically, breaking up `Organizer` is only possible if you can also break up the interface - although you could write a [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), and then delegate each method to a separate class that implements that particular method.

Still, the presence of an interface emphasises the importance of the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle). I often see code bases exhibit this particular problem because the interfaces are too big. If at all possible, make the interfaces as small as possible. I tend to take it to the extreme and define only a single member on each interface.

From another of the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), follows that interfaces should be defined by the clients that use them, not the classes that implement them. Designing interfaces like that often enables you to keep them small, and to the point.

Recall also that a single class can implement multiple interfaces.

## Performance

Another concern regarding the design in the OP is of performance, although I agree with NightOwl888's comment that you're likely in micro-optimisation territory.

In general, you can [compose even large object graphs with confidence](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence). As NightOwl888 also suggests in the comments above, if a dependency has Singleton lifetime, it makes little difference if you inject it, but then end up not using it.

Even if you can't give a dependency like `_service2` Singleton lifetime, I again agree with NightOwl888 that object creation in .NET is fast to the point where you almost can't measure it. And as he also points out, [Injection Constructors should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple).

Even in the rare case where a dependency must have Transient lifetime, and for whatever reason creating an instance is expensive, you can always hide that dependency behind a [Virtual Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern), as I also describe in the article about object graphs.

How you configure all that in Unity, I no longer remember, but if Unity can't deal with that, choose another method of composition, preferably [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di).

Comment: Thanks for beautifully explaining the intricacies to be considered.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you're using [Unit 3 or higher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn170416.aspx), you don't need to do anything special for resolving lazy.

You register your type like you normally would:

```
container.RegisteryType<IMyInterface>()...;
```

And then change the constructor to require lazy:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public Lazy<IMyInterface> _service1;

  public MyClass(Lazy<IMyInterface> service1)
  { 
    _serivce1 = service1;
  }
}
```

Then call whatever you method you need:

```
_service1.Value.MyMethod();
```

Comment: If `MyClass` depends on `IMyInterface`, it's a **leaky abstraction** to change it to depend on `Lazy<IMyInterface>`. This implies that it knows something about the concrete implementation of `IMyInterface` that it shouldn't know. A [Virtual Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) addresses the problem in a more elegant way that doesn't require you to change `MyClass`.